# R Data Frame Slicing?

Tags: r, dataframe, slice

So there is a dataframe called train, and a number called z.  The df train contains a column called spread, and I want to select all rows where spread equals z.  Then if the total number of rows is below 500, I want to select all rows where spread is smaller than (z+1) and larger than (z-1)... and want to continue this process until 500 rows are selected.

```
model<-glm(result~spread, data=train[(train$spread<z +3 & train$spread>z -3 ),])
```

So far all I have is the above, which will grab me some arbitrary number of rows.  To do my method I would do it in a loop.  But want to know is there a way to do this without a loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should do it :

```
head(train[order(abs(train$spread-z)),],500)
```

Take the 500 first element ordered by the distance between spread and z. here the distance is `abs(x-y)`

Testing in a short data set of 20 elements:

```
set.seed(1)
train <- data.frame(spread=sample(1:12,20,replace=TRUE),v=1:20)
z <- 5
##dist(cbind(spread,rep(z,length(spread))))
  transform(train[order(abs(train$spread-z)),],dist=abs(spread-z))
   spread  v dist
2       5  2    0
14      5 14    0
19      5 19    0
1       4  1    1
16      6 16    1
3       7  3    2
5       3  5    2
11      3 11    2
12      3 12    2
8       8  8    3
9       8  9    3
10      1 10    4
13      9 13    4
17      9 17    4
15     10 15    5
20     10 20    5
4      11  4    6
6      11  6    6
7      12  7    7
18     12 18    7
```

Comment: Hmmm - I think I got a bit complex compared to your answer. Haha!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it. Using `lapply` to avoid loops. Find out how wide the "flex" needs to be above and below `z` and then `subset` to that value.

```
showNumRows <- function(flex) {  
    nrow(subset(train, spread>=z-flex & spread <= z+flex))
}


plus.minus.vec = c(0,1,2,3) #use more values if needed
rowvect <- lapply(plus.minus.vec, showNumRows) # gives you the num rows at each z+/- flex level 
optimum.flex <- which(rowvect<500) # tells you the flex value at which you get more than 500 rows

#now use that flex value to get your 500+ rows subset of the df
subset(train, spread>=z-optimum.flex & spread <= z+optimum.flex)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The above is what I thought of, but @agstudy's response is much cleaner and the one-liner you wanted.